# How to implement bootstrap datepicker with text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to use a bootstrap datepicker with my text_field inside form_for.
How should I rewrite

```
 <%= f.text_field :some_date %>
```

line to store the selected date in some_date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date time picker just support `input` type for direct integration. but rails `text_field` create `text area`. So you can't do so directly.

You can either integrate datetimepicker onclick or mousedown event. Like we can do for `div/span`.

If you want to do so you need to override datetimepicker code which check for supported html elements.

code below which should change : [link here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L1274)

```
attachDatePickerElementEvents = function () {
    input.on({
        'change': change,
        'blur': options.debug ? '' : hide,
        'keydown': keydown,
        'keyup': keyup,
        'focus': options.allowInputToggle ? show : ''
    });

    if (element.is('input')) {
        input.on({
            'focus': show
        });
    } else if (component) {
        component.on('click', toggle);
        component.on('mousedown', false);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [Demo & code](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=1&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=ru&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on&beforeShowMonth=on#sandbox) and [API](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
$('field selector').datepicker({
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try and answer